# Ubuntu Cronjob with rsync

Tags: linux, ubuntu, backup, cron, rsync

Currently on workplaces server we run a daily backup, due to size limits we need it to be only each third day (or something like that). We use Rsync to do the backup. What I'm thinking to do is to just change the run time of the script, so insted of daily it will run every third day.

So I want to know wether this is possible? My Concerns are that the size wont shrink because the backup will still do a "3-days backup" insted of just one day. It's hard to explain so I'll show it by exampel.

What I want:

- Day 1 - Run Backup
- Day 2
- Day 3
- Day 4 - Run Backup
- Day 5

What I fear will happen:

- Day 1 - Run Backup
- Day 2 - Backup applied from Day 4
- Day 3 - Backup applied from Day 4
- Day 4 - Run Backup
- Day 5

the crontab job looks like this:

> 5 7 * * * ../rsyncsnapshot.sh daily 30

the script looks like this

```sh
if [ $# != 2 ]; then
echo "Usage: backup.sh interval_name count"
exit 1
fi

NAME=$1
COUNT=$2

TIMESTAMP=`date -u "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z"`
echo "*** Backup started $TIMESTAMP (interval $NAME, count $COUNT) ***"

echo "Deleting $DEST_DIR/$NAME.$((COUNT-1))"
ssh $DEST_HOST rm -rf $DEST_DIR/$NAME.$(($COUNT-1))

for i in `seq $(($COUNT-1)) -1 2`;
do
  j=$(($i-1))
  echo "Moving $DEST_DIR/$NAME.$j to $DEST_DIR/$NAME.$i"
  ssh $DEST_HOST mv $DEST_DIR/$NAME.$j $DEST_DIR/$NAME.$i
done

echo "Copying $DEST_DIR/$NAME.0 to $DEST_DIR/$NAME.1"
ssh $DEST_HOST cp -al $DEST_DIR/$NAME.0 $DEST_DIR/$NAME.1

echo "Copying source ($SRC) to $DEST_HOST:$DEST_DIR/$NAME.0/"
rsync $RSYNC_ARGS $SRC $DEST_HOST:$DEST_DIR/${NAME}.0/
ssh $DEST_HOST touch $DEST_DIR/$NAME.0

TIMESTAMP=`date -u "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z"`
echo "*** Backup ended $TIMESTAMP ***"
echo "Quota as follows:"
ssh $DEST_HOST quota
```

Comment: Where does the script check if it's been 3 days since the last backup?

Comment: If a file changes every day, the daily backups will cause 3 copies of the file to be made every 3 days, but the 3-day backup will only cause 1 copy every 3 days. So you will save space.

Comment: I don't think it checks anywhere, the only code left out is server info and paths :) - So, if I changed the crontab to run every third day, I'd get 1 copy every third day?

Comment: Yes. But you only save space for files that are modified on multiple days between backups. If you change file1 on day 1, file2 on day2, and file3 on day3, there's no savings. The backups will be smaller, but not 1/3.

Comment: Figured as much, would there be a smarter way to do this? I mean to save disk space? Apart from having less to take backup off.

Comment: Save fewer old copies. If you only need 30 days of backups, and you do them every 3 days, you only need 10 old versions instead of 30.

Comment: Right, And where would one change that? I'm not exactly an' expert when it comes to rsync / backup? A quick guess would be in the crontab job where is says daily 30 (change it to daily 10)

Comment: Yes, that 30 is the number of copies to keep. It has nothing to do with rsync or backup, it's just used by the script you posted.

Comment: Ah right, how does one give rep for answers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To reduce the amount of space you use significantly, you'll need to reduce the number of copies you keep. This is the 2nd argument to the script. So if you run every 3 days, and want to keep a month of backups, change it to:

```
../rsyncsnapshot.sh daily 10
```